# Cannot share C++ struct with Rust using CXX bridge

Tags: c++, rust, binding, header-files

I understand C++ `class` definitions must be hidden behind a pointer (`*mut`, `SharedPtr<T>`, etc). But structs seem like they should be "C like".

I am trying to export [CleanupParameters](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/cppapi/structRDKit_1_1MolStandardize_1_1CleanupParameters.html) to the Rust side of the binding.

If I put the struct definition in the root of the CXX bridge module like:

```
#[cxx::bridge(namespace = "RDKit")]
pub mod ffi {
    pub struct CleanupParameters {
        rdbase: String,
    }
    
    unsafe extern "C++" { /* snip */ }
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
warning: ..../rdkit-sys/src/cxx/bridge/mol_standardize.rs.cc:87:10: error: definition of type 'CleanupParameters' conflicts with type alias of the same name
warning:   struct CleanupParameters;
warning:          ^
```

which makes sense, it's like I'm defining a new `CleanupParameters` and not "adopting" the C++ definition, so the name collision makes sense.

But if I try to move the definition in to the extern block:

```
#[cxx::bridge(namespace = "RDKit")]
pub mod ffi {
    unsafe extern "C++" {   
        pub struct CleanupParameters {
            rdbase: String,
        }
    }
}
```

the language is not allowed by the CXX bridge proc macro:

```
  error[cxxbridge]: expected one of: `fn`, `static`, `type`
    ┌─ src/cxx/bridge/mol_standardize.rs:7:13
    │
  7 │         pub struct CleanupParameters {
    │             ^^^^^^ expected one of: `fn`, `static`, `type`
```

which does not make much sense. How can I share "non opaque" structs from C++ into Rust?

Comment: Generally CXX expects your C++ code to include the bindings it generates, not the opposite. In your case you also have C++ data structures (`std::string`, `std::vector`) so it is not possible to share them.

Comment: _"...But structs seem like they should be "C like"...."_ - In C++ the only difference between `class` and `struct` is the default access mode. `class` is `private` and `struct` is `public`.